# Почему приходят пустые массивы?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
// меняю на getElementsByClassName в htnl на class в место id  и ничего не работает а в кансоль приходят пустые массивы почему ?
let divClassForm = document.getElementById("divWindow"); //это передать форму

console.log(divClassForm);
let block = document.getElementById("idBtnForm"); //это присвоить кнопке 
console.log(block);
let clouse = document.querySelector(".styleClouse"); //закрыть крестиком форму
let fonForm = document.querySelector(".fonForm");

block.onclick = function() {
  divClassForm.style.display = "block";
  fonForm.style.display = "block";
};
clouse.onclick = function() {
  divClassForm.style.display = "none";
  fonForm.style.display = "none";
};
```

```css
/* тут форма изнчально 
display:none */
```

```html
<div class="fonForm"></div>
<div class="divClassForm " id="divWindow">/*тут меняю на class добовляю своей кнопке class=" idBtnForm" ничего не происходит*/
  <form action="">

    <div class="styleClouse">
      <div class="div_styleClouseOne"></div>
      <div class="div_styleClouseTwo"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Оставить заявку на обратный звонок</p>
    <!-- <span class="close">&times;</span> -->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" class="texName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш номер телефона" class="textNumbre">
    <input type="submit" value="Отсавить заявку на звонок" class="btnForm">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let block = document.getElementById("idBtnForm");
```

Ты пытаешься получить элемент по id "idBtnForm" которого у тебя нет в html.
Попробуй просто указать другой id в submit и на него повесить функцию

getElementById - это один элемент, а getElementsByClassName - это живая коллекция элементов. Вообще где указано getElements - это живая коллекция с элементами.

И что бы обратиться к элементу по getElementsByClassName нужно указывать индекс элемента, к которому ты хочешь обратиться. А если ты хочешь ко всем элементом с данным классом, то нужно создавать цикл